# Jquery preloader bar help

Tags: jquery, preloader

I have just seen this website which use a preloading bar. I have searched everywhere for something like this that can be used for loading content into a page or the page itself but I have found nothing apart from this but it extremely clunky...http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/how-to-create-a-stylish-loading-bar-as-gmail-in-javascript/

Anyone know of such a plugin?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

How about jQuery UI progressbar widget? http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: How does this actually know how much has loaded?